# Knowledge gap when setting up Passenger and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to set up Passenger, Rails and Nginx. Nginx correctly routes to Passenger but when I load the page I get the following error:

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:219:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:333:in `running_bundler'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:217:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

What I don't understand is:

- Why there are a bunch of references to Ruby 1.9.1? I am using 1.9.3 as default and have installed Bundler on both the global 1.9.3 and the user specific 1.9.3.
- How can I change which user Passenger runs on?
- Am I supposed to install a bunch of gems in Passenger's user as well?
- Do I need to grant www-data (that passenger runs on AFAIK) access to some gem directory?
- Should I augment GEM_HOME and if so, which gem directory do I point to?
- Why isn't this setup during installation of the nginx passenger bundle?

I have installed bundler basically everywhere I can, but must have missed something important.

- How does RVM complicate things?
- What do I need to be aware of when using RVM?
- Does every user in the system get the Ruby version I set in RVM? How can I make it so if not?

I feel I am close to grasping the entire thing now but haven't been able to read myself to the solution.

If you go to http://privateering.me:8000/ you can see the rest of the error dump.

Comment: As far as I know 1.9.1 is used in the path, even if you have 1.9.3 running. This is not a problem in itself. I cannot think of any good reason why anyone thought having 1.9.1 in the path is a good idea, though. Also, read about `rvm wrapper` which generates you binary stubs (of e.g. passenger) with the right gemset and ruby version.

Comment: I know passenger is configured to use a wrapper _somewhere_ since I saw it in a config file. The problem seems to be that www-data hasn't got the ruby version required nor the gems either. At this point I feel like it would be better to let passenger run on www-data, or change the GEM_PATH to point to the gem directory of the user I use to install everything

Comment: IIRC, back in the dark ages of, oh, a couple years ago, there was a big stink among the maintainers of the *nix repositories that Ruby development moved too fast and was causing a burden on them as they tried to keep up. As a result, "they" decided to stick with Ruby191 as the designation of the Ruby 1.9+ versions. RVM, which installs from source or an image, doesn't rely on repos, so its version numbers are more sane because they come from the Ruby developers themselves, without the repo maintainers. I recommend using RVM or rbenv as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's morning! I've had my coffee! Let's go!

> What I don't understand is why there are a bunch of references to ruby
>   1.9.1?

As tessi mentioned, 1.9.1 in the path is normal for some builds of Ruby 1.9.3. It's weird and confusing, but it is what it is. This is not immediately concerning by itself.

> Furthermore, how can I change which user passenger runs on?

Phusion has some very good [documentation for Phusion/Nginx](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html) which includes all of the configuration parameters. But it's probably not necessary because, as the [user-related docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerUserSwitching) will tell you, Passenger by default will attempt to run each application as the user that owns it.

> Am I supposed to install a bunch of gems on passenger's user as well?

Maybe. Probably not. See above. Whenever possible, there is no one "Passenger user". Only if user switching is unavailable will Passenger fall back to operating as a single user (whatever nginx is configured for).

> Why isn't this setup during installation of the nginx passenger bundle?

Because Passenger is simply a multitenant, polyglot application server. It doesn't know if you're running one application or a hundred, Ruby or Python, Rails or Sinatra or Merb or something home-brewed. Passenger's job is to run the application once you tell it what that is; your job is to get each application into a runnable state.

> How does RVM complicate things? What do I need to be aware of when using RVM? Does every user in the system get the ruby version I set in RVM? How can I make it so if not?

RVM complicates things sufficiently. By default, it's installed on a single-user basis and affects only a single user. This is its exact intended use case: when I'm logged in, *I* want a different Ruby and don't want to pollute the system. There are additional complications due to the particular way RVM works.

But Phusion realizes some people are going to be using RVM in production for whatever reason [and covers that situation in the installation documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#rubygems_generic_install).

Most pain involving RVM and Passenger is easily avoided by cutting RVM out of the picture. Unless you're on an extremely exotic platform, building a modern Ruby is a matter of `./configure && make && make install`. One line and you've got a stable, system-wide Ruby in `/usr/local`, easily accessible by you, Passenger, and everything else.

Comment: Thanks, this was great. I have also been skeptical to using rvm on a production machine. I want to limit the possibility of error an thus only use exactly what I need for running my site. But every tutorial I've read has recommended it. I have now solved it finally, passenger_ruby (in the sites nginx config file) had to point to the ruby version I wanted to use. I will mark this as the answer.